# Coq QuickChick : Making propery Checkable, Decidable, Arbitrary (Gen)

Tags: coq

I am trying to test simple conjecture with QuickChick:

```
Conjecture lists_eq : forall (l : list string), l = l. 

QuickChick lists_eq.
```

but I get this error:

```
Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
?arg_2 : "Checkable (forall l : list string, l = l)"
```

I know I need to make my property Instance of class Checkable, but how should I do it?

I made decidability on two lists (successfully)

```
Instance EqLists_Dec (x y : list string) : Dec (x = y).
```

I made Arbitrary for list (successfully)
Instance gen_list_string : Gen (list string)

But I couldn't make Property checkable, I know that bool type is Checkable in QC.

Here is the code, plese advice. Maybe I am doing it all in a wrong way.

```
From QuickChick Require Import QuickChick.
Require Import List ZArith. Import ListNotations.
Import QcNotation.
Set Warnings "-extraction-opaque-accessed,-extraction".
Require Import String. Local Open Scope string. 

Definition genListString : G (list string) :=
  elems_ ["Two" ; "Three"]
         [
           [ "One" ; "Nstasss" ; "SomeStr" ; "Yellow" ];
           [ "111" ; "2222" ; "33333SomeStr" ; "44444Yellow" ]
         ].

(* Sample genListString.  *)

Instance gen_list_string : Gen (list string) :=
  {
    arbitrary := genListString
  }.

Notation "P '?'" :=
  (match (@dec P _) with
   | left _ => true
   | right _ => false
   end)
    (at level 100).

Instance EqLists_Dec (x y : list string) : Dec (x = y).
Proof. dec_eq. Defined.

(* Problem in this function, couldn't make it work*)
Instance checkableDec `{P : Prop} `{Dec P} : Checkable P :=
  {
    checker p := if P? then ret ok else ret Failure
  }.

Conjecture lists_eq : forall (l : list string), l = l. 

QuickChick lists_eq.

(*
Unable to satisfy the following constraints:
?arg_2 : "Checkable (forall l : list string, l = l)"
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

`checkableDec` already exists in QuickChick. You are actually missing a `Shrink` instance:

```
Instance Shrink_string : Shrink string :=
  {| shrink x := [] |}.
```

---

To debug this you can `Set Typeclasses Debug` and then look at where the trace says `no match for ...`. You have to be careful of false positives because there is backtracking, but with persistence and experience you'll get the hang of it.